# Can't add existing has many models to non-existing parent model in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 2 models - `Widget` and `Photo`. `Widget` has_many `photos` and set accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos.

I upload photos before creating of widget, so params comes with null `widget_id` attribute in photo model. And when I'm trying to save widget it says that can't find photo with proper widget_id.

How to handle it? Are there any hooks for it? **I can't create Widget before photos**

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :photos

  default_scope {order('position ASC')}
end

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :widget

  has_attached_file :image
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Stacktracke: http://pastebin.com/qMDmwdbx

Comment: version is 4.2.5, have no any validations. It's not a validation problem. Moreover, it's behavior from out of the box. Just need a elegant way to handle it.

Comment: belongs_to :widget, no validations, everything is pretty simple, see my previous comment.

Comment: It would be helpful to include your model code(just the necessary part)  in your question.

Comment: How did you create the `widget_id` column in your database? Did you use `null: false`?

Comment: Yes, it's has ```null: false```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to show an example of the params that you pass into create method for `Widget`

Comment: can you post the exact error message

Comment: @coderVishal the message is **Couldn't find Photo with ID=182 for Widget with ID=**

Comment: also the exact line in which errors occurs, maybe a few lines above and below it too, for context

Comment: @coderVishal stacktrace http://pastebin.com/qMDmwdbx